# How can I flip one texture with a mirror?

Tags: texturing, mirror

I'm testing some textures with this model but when I press the U button it flips all the textures and I only want to flip the eyes textures. help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to flip eyes texture? It's looking quite logical on the first screenshot. As to question itself you can't flip only part of the texture with Mirror modifier only. Apply it and do whatever you want on UV map or assign eyes on another material

Comment: or what you could do would be changing the texture